# filter logs by username instead of sid

Tags: cmd, command, event-viewer, qxmlquery, wevtutil

I want to filter some logs for specific username. In event viewer, you can enter username in the mentioned field and it will filter your logs. but I want to use cmd ( **wevtutil** ) , so I should use xml query to filter my logs. But the problem appears here . In xml query you can only enter sid of the user you are looking for ( in system[security[@Userid]]] ).
Is it possible somehow to use username instead of sid?

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RaoWg.png)
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aq05x.png)

notes:
In event viewer, when you enter the username , it convert the username to sid and use the sid in its xml query. I don't have any idea how does it occur.

And I should mention a note here that is :
Some people suggest me to use "target username" to filter my logs. But it is not what I'm looking for. "target username" only deals with login logs.

Comment: Thanks. It worked and it was very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just use the UserName to retrieve their SID for use in your `wevtutil` command.

From the Command Prompt, *([cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd))*:

```sh
For /F %G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe UserAccount Where "Name='KnownUserName'" Get SID 2^>NUL ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe "-"') Do @%SystemRoot\System32\wevtutil.exe CommandLineOptions
```

You'd simply replace `KnownUserName` and `CommandLineOptions`, and substitute their SID with `%G`.

Or from a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file):

```sh
@For /F %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe UserAccount Where
 "Name='KnownUserName'" Get SID 2^>NUL ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe "-"'
) Do @%SystemRoot\System32\wevtutil.exe CommandLineOptions
```

Obviously you'd replace `KnownUserName` and `CommandLineOptions` again, and substitute their SID this time with `%%G`.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps everyone because I had the same problem. To query events related to a specific user. Below, `Jsmith` will be our specific user in question. You want to use either `TargetUserName` or `SubjectUserName`.

```
wevtutil qe security /q:"*[EventData/Data[@Name='TargetUserName']='Jsmith']"
```

OR

```
wevtutil qe security /q:"*[EventData/Data[@Name='SubjectUserName']='Jsmith']"
```